# Why the order of the UITableView Cells changed when I changed the size of the cell and reload?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got a tableView to display some information like following image.[image: image 1]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if cellStates[indexPath.section] == .unfold {
            cellStates[indexPath.section] = .fold
        } else { 
            cellStates[indexPath.section] = .unfold
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

The cell would be expanded under fold state, like following image.[image: image 2]
If you touch it again, it should be folded again, like image 1.

**Then here comes the problem.**
As what we can see in image 2, there are three cells out side the screen.
No1, No2, No5 outside. And No3, No4 Inside. No3 is the cell we just touched.
When I touch No3 cell again to fold it, the order changed to No3, No4, No1, No2, No5.
[image: image 3]

It seems the cells that inside screen have been lifted to the top.
I'm confused in this, what's really going on? How to avoid?
The height of the cell depends on the unchanged data source, so it will mess things up.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WBCell") as! WBTableViewCell
        cell.controller = self

        let state = cellStates[indexPath.section]
        if state == .initial {
            let data = dataSource[index]
            cell.initial(data: data)
            cellStates[indexPath.section] = .fold
        } else if state == .fold {
            cell.switchTo(unFolded: false) // Update autolayout constrains via SnapKit
        } else {
            cell.switchTo(unFolded: true)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me cellForRowAt indexPath method ?

Comment: Also, do you want to unfold the section or the row?

Comment: @Paulw11 There is just one cell in every section.

Comment: You don't set the `data` property in the folded and unfolded cases. There is no guarantee that the cell that was used for a particular index path last time will be used for that indexpath next time. Your `cellForRowAt` must always fully configure the cell

Comment: @Paulw11 The cell will fetch online images, so if I fully set up the cell every time, it would cost a lot(I have not tried it yet). I will let you know wether it works once I try.
`

Comment: You should use a cache such as NSCache or SDWebImage to cache the images, but you have to set the cell up correctly each time